# How to correctly install this mouse?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, mouse

I'm switching from windows completely now that Counter Strike: Global Offencive is out for linux, this was the only thing holding me.

I have everything configured, exept for one thing, my [mouse](http://www.tecnocity.com.uy/shop/accesorios/mouse-gamer-7d-gm-18/).

I would like to know how to install it in Ubuntu 14.04

EDIT: [lsusb](http://pastebin.com/1X639Ekb)

Comment: Does the mouse work basically and you just want to get the additional buttons to work or does it not work at all?

Comment: When my PC boots up I can use the mouse on the BIOS and when ubuntu starts stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 14.04 runs on kernel version 3.13, but the driver for your mouse was only added to later kernels as per [bug report #1316768](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1316768) (note the same USB device ID 04d9:a070).

You can install a newer kernel

- as described in [Kernel/MainlineBuilds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds?action=show&redirect=KernelMainlineBuilds#Installing_upstream_kernels) or
- in this case more simply with the package `linux-generic-lts-utopic` from the [Canonical Kernel Team PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa):

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-kernel-team/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-utopic
  ```

Afterwards you need to reboot into the new kernel.

Answer (score 1):

HID devices should be auto detected upon startup is it a special mouse with extra functions? if so you may need to.

```
sudo apt-get install qjoypad
sudo qjoypad --notray
```

map extra keys

Comment: It has 3 more extra buttons, I installed qjoypad and did " sudo qjoypad --no tray" but it gave me this error: Failed to find a layout named tray

Comment: Try the edit - looking at [the documentation](http://qjoypad.sourceforge.net/doc/c113.html#AEN115), the argument should be `--notray` not `--no tray`.

Comment: It doesn't recognize the mice has a joystick :( I have been searching and I found that modifing xorg.conf could be an option but I have no experience doing that.

Comment: What kind of mouse is it? What extras does it have? please do a 
lsusb
and copy paste results

Comment: 1-The mice has 2 extra buttons, 1 'fire' button, the two regular right  click and left click and the wheel which you can also click, the last extra feature is a button which changes the dpi of the mouse from 400 to 3500 dpi.

Comment: when you connect your mouse to the pc does it generate a new file in /dev/input/